# Where to cache files locally

Tags: .net, wpf, isolatedstorage, temp

Our WPF desktop application downloads some images at startup from a server in the cloud.
Since the download takes some time (up to a minute) and the images rarely change I would like to cache them to the user's disk so that they won't be loaded on subsequent startups.

Where would be the appropriate place to put them? The files may live for a long time (years), but if they are deleted, the startup will just download them again.

The options I've considered is to put them in the TEMP folder (which path I get from `Path.GetTempPath()`) or in `IsolatedStorage`. I don't know which would be best or if there is a better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for ApplicationData if I wanted the pictures to be accessed only by the logged in user as it is:

> [The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data for the current roaming user.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8)

You can access it like this:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "AppName", "Images");
```

And I would go for CommonApplicationData if I wanted the pictures to be accessed by all users at this machine as it is:

> [The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by all users.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8)

You can access it like this:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "AppName", "Images");
```

Comment: Use `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` if downloaded data should be available for all users.

Comment: @Clemens not CommonApplicationData but ApplicationData. These are different

Comment: I mean CommonApplicationData: *The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by all users.*

Comment: I get it. But the OP wants to cache data for a certain user. So when other users log in and upload their photo - it should be stored in a separate folder. With the CommonApplicationData the folder will be shared between all users that have access to the computer. In case of ApplicationData (the folder I suggested) - the photo will be accessed only by the current logged in user.

Comment: "*wants to cache data for a certain user*" - where exactly did they tell that? The "*user's disk*" is not the user's app data folder. You should mention both options and their difference in your answer.

Comment: Well, no where. I agree. I did mess up here. Let me fix the answer. I'm sorry for that.